# How can I add a custom property to a class inherited from MFC's CEdit?

Tags: mfc

I'm working on a project which makes use of an inherited version of the CEdit class from MFC.

Up until now, we've been able to use a regular CEdit in the Dialog Editor because the functionality in the inherited class had no interaction with the visual dialog editor.

Now, we have a requirement to implement something like a 'linked list CEdit' which contains a field referencing the 'next' CEdit control, similar to the concept of tab-indexing each control.

It's obviously easy to add a field pointing to another control, but how do I cause this new field to appear in the list of properties in the visual dialog editor?

[image]

I've been reading about custom ActiveX controls in the book 'Programming Windows with MFC' but this approach seems quite involved, because we have an existing structure where the inherited control is not isolated in its own library project. It's just a regular CPP file inheriting from CEdit.

So - should I grind through the custom ActiveX control from Prosise, or is there a simpler way to see my custom properties in the visual designer?